# OCaml Where did I make an error?

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

How to correct this error ?

```
type 'a drzewo = | Puste | Wezel of 'a * 'a drzewo * 'a drzewo

let rec inorder t =
  match t with
  | Puste -> print_int (-1)
  | Wezel (v, l, r) -> (inorder l; print_int v; inorder r)

let tree =
  (1,
   (Wezel (2, (Wezel (3, Puste, Puste)),
      (Wezel (4, (Wezel (5, Puste, Puste)), Puste)))),
   (Wezel (6, Puste, Puste)))

let _ = inorder tree
```

And the log of error:

> let _ = inorder tree;; Error: This expression has type int * int
>   drzewo * int drzewo
>          but an expression was expected of type int drzewo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
let tree =
  (1,
   (Wezel (2, (Wezel (3, Puste, Puste)),
      (Wezel (4, (Wezel (5, Puste, Puste)), Puste)))),
   (Wezel (6, Puste, Puste)))
```

You didn't add `Wezel` in front.

---

It should be:

```
let tree =
      Wezel (1,
       (Wezel (2, (Wezel (3, Puste, Puste)),
          (Wezel (4, (Wezel (5, Puste, Puste)), Puste)))),
       (Wezel (6, Puste, Puste)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is already very informative, just carefully re-read it again. The type of 'tree' is 'int * int drzewo * int drzewo' (a triple), but it must be 'int drzewo' (because inorder has type 'int drzewo -> unit').

So just correct it:

```
let tree = Wezel (1,
          (Wezel (2, (Wezel (3, Puste, Puste)),
              (Wezel (4, (Wezel (5, Puste, Puste)), Puste)))),
          (Wezel (6, Puste, Puste)))
```